# Tag iPhone 5s cannot be created in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

I think [iphone-5s](/questions/tagged/iphone-5s) should be created as there are increasing number of questions regarding this new device.

See [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone-5s+is%3Aquestion)

The tag can't be created because [iphone-5](/questions/tagged/iphone-5) already exist and there is some restriction given that the difference is only a letter.

Comment: We can't just create a tag. We need questions that would fit under the tag.

Comment: how about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928591/see-if-touch-id-is-enabled-on-iphone-5s/18928657#18928657

Comment: I don't know if we really need a different tag, but there are already several questions and the problem is a tecnical one as I noted in my suggested edit.

Comment: Officially it's iphone-5-swag

Comment: I really don't understand the point of these iPhone tags. The iPhone is just a device that uses other programs to function, such as iOS. Why aren't we just using those tags? Am I missing something huge here? For example, how would [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928591/see-if-touch-id-is-enabled-on-iphone-5s) benefit from an [tag:iphone-5s] tag?

Comment: Well, the 5s does have three new things going for it hardware wise -- a 64-bit processor, the new fingerprint reader, and the new motion detection chip.  But wouldn't those *features* make better tags?

Comment: See also http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/plural-guard-registering-false-positives-on-this-site

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create this tag because it looks like a plural for the existing tag. Only moderators can create such a tag.

But that wouldn’t be a good idea: Stack Overflow is about *software*, not hardware. If you ask a question about a specific API or software feature in the new iPhone, use tags for this API or feature. They will probably exist in the next iPhone too, and then the hardware tag would be useless, while the software tag would still help.